# putting a select dropdown under the search input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Suppose I have a container that has a input search, what I want to achieve is to put exactly under the search input the select dropdown, select dropdown has the same width with the search input (just like on the search with autocomplete ) right now this is the what I have tried so far.

```
        <div class="container position-relative" id="wrapper">
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row float-right mr-0">
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control ml-sm-2" type="text" id="searchUser" placeholder= "Search by Name or Username...." aria-label="Search">
                        <span class="input-group-append" id="searchBtn">
                         <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="position-absolute" style="width:400px; z-index: 1; right:0; top:45px; ">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
                <option>1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

any idea how to implement?

this is the result that i have right now

[image]

Comment: ever considered using a datalist? type something but let it select out of a fixed group, which appears as a drop down as search, however you are not forced to pick anything of it, but helps you navigate through it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to leverage [css box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to achieve that. A very simple code snippet attached for your understanding.

```css
#input1, #select1{
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    -ms-box-sizing:content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
    box-sizing:content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box; 
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="input box"><br />
<select id="select1">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go through about bootstrap css and try to understand the classes available for forms. The forms controlles can be styled as inline and horizontal. As i could see that you have given the class form-inline to your forms hence the contorlls were place on the same line. Please check the below code which i think will solve your problem

```
<div class="container" id="wrapper">
 <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row ">
                <div class="input-group col-5">
                    <input class="form-control " type="text" id="searchUser" placeholder= "Search by Name or Username...." aria-label="Search">
                    <span class="input-group-append" id="searchBtn">
                     <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-5">
                     <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
                        <option>1</option>
                    </select>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript you can achieve something like this, What you can do here first create a div and inside this div put one input and an entire list of all possible matches and onkeyup of the input if input match some list-items show them and onclick of them put there value inside in Input, Its my try (Based on available information) ,You can do pretty much same thing with bootstrap using vanilla javascript. I Hope this will help, Still a lot of things can be improved in this code

```js
// Get input 

let input = document.querySelector("#userName");

let allListItems = document.querySelectorAll(".lists");

input.addEventListener("keyup", checkMatch);

function checkMatch(){
   
   if (input.value !== ``) {
     

        allListItems.forEach(function(value){
            if (value.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(`${input.value.toLowerCase()}`)) {
                value.classList.add("showMe")
                value.addEventListener("click", complete);

                function complete(){
                    input.value = value.innerHTML;
                   allListItems.forEach(function(value){
                       value.classList.remove("showMe");
                   })
                }
            }else{
                value.classList.remove("showMe");
            }
        })

   };

}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box-container{
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
#userName{
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0.5px solid #212121;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.box-container ul{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.lists{
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 45px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    display: none;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.showMe{
    display: block;
}
p{
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>AutoComplete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box-container">
        <input type="text" id="userName" placeholder="Enter username here">
        <ul>
            <li class="lists">Alex</li>
            <li class="lists">Mox</li>
            <li class="lists">Karl</li>
            <li class="lists">NightRider</li>
            <li class="lists">Yk</li>
            <li class="lists">heroX</li>
            <li class="lists">ari</li>
            <li class="lists">hant</li>
            <li class="lists">tin</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <p>Try Alex , Mox , Karl</p>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```